# Code works fine without subquery, why to use it?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

```
newest = Comment.objects.filter(post=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-created_at')
posts = Post.objects.annotate(newest_commenter_email=Subquery(newest.values('email')[:1]))
```

And,

```
newest = Comment.objects.filter(post=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-created_at')
posts = Post.objects.annotate(newest_commenter_email=newest.values('email')[:1])
```

Both, works fine then why use a `Subquery`, what are its advantages?

Comment: Can you share the SQL generated by these statements?

Comment: check both quires execution plan

Comment: Both have the same SQL and, execution time, with no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Subqueries can make it easier to write complex queries, as you can break down the query into smaller, more manageable pieces.
[How to use subquery](https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-orm-cookbook/en/latest/subquery.html)

In Your case that query wasn't so complicated.

Comment: When I tried those things without using Subquery() of Django, that worked fine too i.e... using the Subquery keyword is not making any difference.

Comment: well, here you are using Django ORM. When you run an orm, django  converters the orm in to sql and then sql runs on database. subquery only exists in orm. it's only there is to help developer to write complex query.
It's not a database syntax. 
Like lambda in python. You can use lambda most of the time instant of def function. but there will be some case where function is the best way or lambda is the best way.